# How to upload file on google drive using my android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I start with [google drive sdk](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android). I follows steps which describe in that post.

But I face problem in `Step 3: Create and Configure an Android Project`

[image: Add Google APIs]

I cant find options in my eclipse so I add plugins for google. After installation of plugins, Eclipse give errors and we now update my SDK also. So for that I update my SDK but now All projects giving me error in eclipse. I cant run any projects. So I use my old SDK back.

Now I stuck with this How to create Project for Google Drive and how to integrate it.

I need to upload file from my android application to Google Drive.

Please help me to find this.

**EDIT**

Now I successfully create project with error free. But when I run project it give me following errors.

```
 12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.rarenoice.screen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-12 11:05:08.788: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

At Following line :-

```
private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
 credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this,
                DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```

Comment: "Eclipse give errors " and the errors are?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. "Your Project contains error please fix them before run" showing while no error in project. So that I use my old SDK and succefully create project and add Libraries at build path. Now project give me this error :- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential

Comment: add the full error code and stack trace as an [edit] to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: I edit my question. Please Look.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: hey same here , I am facing  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCreden‌​tial this error, how to fix it

Comment: hey @Hardy do you have any idea how to use this in Android Studio?

Comment: No buddy. @Rohit I dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) jars to your project, as explained in Step 3 of the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) you are following.

You can also watch this video where I go through all the steps to build the same quickstart application for Android: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ied1CjJ0iP0

Comment: is adding Google play service help you solve the error? But google play service do not contain the GoogleAccountCredential class.

Comment: @Claudio I first remove all jar files from libs folder then again add jars from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.12.0-beta.zip&can=2&q=). And then add google play service.jar to build path. And I see your video on youtube which you give me link so one thing i not follow is that my package name in project is not same as package name specified on Google API. So i think it also an problem which i facing. Then I clean my project and run it give me success.