# Accessing google drive from Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I  followed steps listing at [How to upload file on google drive using my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833358/how-to-upload-file-on-google-drive-using-my-android-application/14584010#14584010)  and  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ied1CjJ0iP0  .But i am getting these errors .Please help me out .I have one more issue what if i want upload some file created my application to some user's(not added on phone) drive without user interaction

```
 01-29 18:48:07.925: E/Trace(5134): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6566
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134): java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:353)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:100)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:269)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:408)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:328)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:449)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at com.example.googlevideo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:103)
 01-29 18:48:26.955: E/AndroidRuntime(5134):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Please check that you are correctly authorized. If you are not, there will be a null pointer exception there.

Comment: i apologize in advance if i am asking a silly question , but  how can i check that  if i am authorized ??

Answer (score 0):

This exception was because my request was not valid ;the  package name i had given in Google console didn't match with what i was using in my application.